# customise correlation heatmap in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, correlation

I am new to python and i am trying to make a correlation heatmap on seaborn. Could anyone tell me how to customise the default values on the right of the heatmap with my own correlation cutoffs? I get something like the one in the picture but i want to customise with my own cutoffs and three values instead of four.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
new_df = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G','E']]
sns.heatmap(new_df.corr(), annot = False,square=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the tick marks that display on the colorbar.

If so the heatmap function has an attribute **cbar_kws** which accepts a dictionary as input. A potential solution is:

```
sns.heatmap(
    new_df.corr(),
    annot = False,
    square=True,
    cbar_kws={'ticks': [0.25, .5, 1]}
)
```

[Seaborn heatmap documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap)
[Matplotlib Colorbar documentation (for the key words)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but the cbar and the colours of heatmap did not change. How can I change everything according to the cutoffs?  So for instance, if there are three values, I would like three colours on the cbar and the heatmap. Thanks